# Padding issue with parent Container Widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can i match parent widget size?

I want to have list features in Grid builder, Same time Grid's child widget size should match with parent widget. Grid should not scroll, so implemented 3*3 matrix formula and works but size not matching based on parent.

**Code :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../constants.dart';
import '../../../size_config.dart';
import 'dart:math';


class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/HomeScreen";

  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // You have to call it on your starting screen
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      shadowColor: Colors.white70,
      elevation: 10,
      title: const Text(
        'WELCOMe',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: kPrimaryColor,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      leading: Container(),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: appBar,
      body: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static const List<List<String>> featuresValues = [
    [
      "WELCOMe",
      "WELCOMe",
      "WELCOMe",
    ],
    [
      "WELCOMe",
      "WELCOMe",
      "WELCOMe",
    ],
    [
      "WELCOMe",
      "WELCOMe",
      "WELCOMe"
    ]
  ];
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: HexToColor('#FFFFFF'),
              // decoration:  BoxDecoration(
              //   color: Colors.white,
              //   boxShadow: [
              //     BoxShadow(
              //       color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              //       blurRadius: 15,
              //       offset: Offset(15, 0), // changes position of shadow
              //     ),
              //   ], // Make rounded corner of border
              // ),
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
              // color: Colors.white38,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/Profile Image.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "KARTHIKEYAN",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Executive",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 8,
            child: Container(
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
              color: Colors.black12,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) ...[
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) ...[
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                              children: [
                                                Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                                  children: [
                                                    CircleAvatar(
                                                      radius: 20,
                                                      child: ClipOval(
                                                        child: Image.asset(
                                                          "assets/images/Profile Image.png",
                                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(featuresValues[i][j]),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            // margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color : Colors.orange,
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                // color: Colors.grey,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ]
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ]
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black26,
                              blurRadius: 15.0,
                              offset: Offset(0.0, 0.5))
                        ], color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // const Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                // boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[-5],
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    offset: Offset(-1, -8), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ], // Make rounded corner of border
              ),
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
              // color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HexToColor extends Color {
  static _hexToColor(String code) {
    return int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000;
  }

  HexToColor(final String code) : super(_hexToColor(code));
}
```

Sample Design:

[image: img]

**Result:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you include an image that  you are trying to archive?

Comment: With in white box there is space between all side, that orange box size is issue

Comment: well, is there any issue using `GridView`?

Comment: I can use grid view, scroll will enable by default.. I want to 3*3 Container in that white box...Fixed content

Comment: How can increase the orange box size based Container w & h?

Answer (score 1):

You can `LayoutBuilder` to get parent size and use three 3* column<Row<3>>. I am using `GridView.count` with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` for your case. You can follow bellow widget.

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                /// outside padding
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

                child: SizedBox(
                  /// perItem height * 3  = screen width
                  height: constraints.maxWidth,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    // if you need spacing
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: List.generate(
                      9,
                      (index) => Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        child: Text(
                          index.toString(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... seems going out of bounds..i tried your code online pls find the SS https://ibb.co/2q1mJF2

Comment: This overflow is coming because your output width>Height. You need to handle it on top level, the one you like for scrolling behavior.  I am using `SingleChildScrollView` for demo case.

Comment: My entire page should not scroll, We can achieve this in iOS Native development.

Comment: you are testing on web, can test on your device without `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: all child box should comes equal w&h based on parent widget...content should not overflow both vertical and horizontal

Comment: Did you test on the snippet on your device?

Comment: I tested same result only

Comment: It is possible I am not getting the concept or if you are adding widget on top level, you can try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. And for the height it is depended on screen width/3 , therefore sometime it will need to be scroll case like orientation.  And it will only scroll if the viewport doesn't fit, depends on your full widget structure. You may adding extra widget that doesn't fit to the screen.

Comment: The child layout must be adjusted inside the parent layout even if the child layout is increased from 2*2 to 3*3 and the scroll must not happen inside the parent layout

Comment: Child has to occupy the parent widget https://ibb.co/fSJZL5L

Comment: Do you understand the question?

Comment: Check my answer @ Yeasin..Is it possible with Grid builder?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with following solution, @Yeasin Sheikh thank you much..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home:  LoopWidget()
    );
  }
}
class LoopWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  static const List<List<String>> featuresValues = [
    [
      "",
      "",
      "",
    ],
    [
      "",
      "",
      "",
    ],
    [
      "",
      "",
      ""
    ]
  ];
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              /// outside padding
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                 children: <Widget>[
                  
                    for (int i = 0; i < featuresValues.length; i++) ...[
                         Row(
                           children: [
                              for (int j = 0; j < featuresValues[i].length; j++) ...[
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                           Container(
                                             height : constraints.maxHeight / 3 - 8,
                                             width : constraints.maxWidth / 3 - 8,
                                             color: Colors.green,
                                           ),
                                       
                                        ],
                                   )
                               ],
                            ],
                        ),
                      ],
                  ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```